# i18next changes language without any input

Tags: node.js, express, i18next

I am trying to set up i18next on my node.js app. I have for now two languages : fr-CA and en-US.

I would like to have fr-CA as default language. I set it up like this in my app.js, before the configuration, :

```
i18next.init({
  debug: true, 
  lng: 'fr-CA', 
  ignoreRoutes: [
   'img/', 
   'public/', 
    'stylesheets/', 
    'js/'
  ]
});
```

Here is my folder structure

```
locales/
  dev/
    translation.json
  en/
    translation.json
  fr-CA/
    translation.json
  fr/
    translation.json
```

I do a console log on server launch to see what's the i18next.lng() value, and it says `fr-CA`. However, as soon as I load a page, the console says `currentLng set to: en-US`. So it always tries to load the locales/en/translation.json file.

The debug shows that when launching the server it loads the fr-CA, fr and dev files. But as soon as a page launches it loads the en file and it's like it completely forgot about fr-CA. My browser is in English so I guess it takes this value from there. But I can't seem to find why it changes.

Did I miss something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

defining a fallbackLanguage is done by setting `fallbackLng` not `lng`!

```
i18next.init({
  debug: true, 
  fallbackLng: 'fr-CA', 
  ignoreRoutes: [
   'img/', 
   'public/', 
    'stylesheets/', 
    'js/'
  ]
});
```